# How to find indexOf element in two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, collections, indexof

I'm on a beginner level in C# so I'm not sure if it's what I use might be considered as a two-dimensional array. But anyway it's a List of the string array.

```
List<string[]> cars = new List<string[]>();
```

I want to know how would I use **IndexOf method** if I wanted to call specific index and display the array elements inside of it? For example, my three textboxes set the following data to 3 elements of each index:

CarName = "Audi"

Model = "A3"

color = "black"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cars.Add(new string[3]);
    cars[cars.Count-1][0] = textBox1.Text;
    cars[cars.Count-1][1] = textBox2.Text;
    cars[cars.Count-1][2] = textBox3.Text;
}
```

So if I type the name of any car (BMW, AUDI, FORD) in another textBox, all the related information(model and color) should be printed out on the labels. I think **IndexOf** method is what I need in this case but how would I implement it for the type of collection I use?

Comment: `I'm not sure if it's what I use might be considered as a two-dimensional array.`, no, but it's close (and in a mathematical sense it's surly 2 dimensional).... in this case we speak of a `List of array`'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong data structure here. You need a class with three properties, then you can have a list of `Cars` instead of `string` arrays, and search by specific property using LINQ.

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; } 
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

var cars = new List<Car>();

cars.Add(new Car { Name = textBox1.Text, Color = textBox2.Text, Model = textBox3.Text });
```

To search for a car by a specific `Brand`:

```
var car = cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Brand == "BMW")
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return the first car that matches the criteria if exists, otherwise, it will return null.

Note: It is a good practice to give meaningful names to your controls. For example: use `TxtBrand`, `TxtModel`, `TxtColor` etc. So the code would be more readable.

Comment: Beat me to it.... although I was also suggesting to use `brand` instead of `Name`. ;-)

Comment: I agree, Brand makes more sense instead of Name. I've updated the answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: let's suppose I have a "next" and "prev" buttons and I need to go back and forth in the elements  within the scope of size of List. What would your suggestion be?

Comment: @CavidHummatov you mean going through multiple cars of same brand? You can use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, it will return all cars instead of a single car.  And you will need to keep track of an index, increase it by one when pressed next, and decrease when pressed back.

Comment: thanks for clearing it up for me. I still can't help wondering about how Indexof method is implemented for this type of collections. Could you also mention that matter briefly?

Comment: @CavidHummatov you can do it the same way, using LINQ. `cars.Where(a => a[0] == "BMW")`

Comment: another problem came out of it : `var car = cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Brand == textBox4.Text)` ,   **Cannot convert from WindFormApp1.Car  to string** if I need to to smth like this `label1.Text = car`

Comment: how to deal with it?

Comment: @CavidHummatov no problem,if this answer solved your issue please [consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).